# Links in master page with tilde URLs give 404 depending on the page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page with links to other pages in the site. Those links use tilde paths (like "~/dir1/page2.aspx"). On most of the pages in the site that use this master page, there is no problem.

The problem only occurs on a few pages that use the master page. The links are VERY wrong; it tries to use the ~ as part of the link (so they are "http://server.domain.com/~/dir1/page2.aspx").

It's as if it is treating the tilde as a literal under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're not properly resolving the URLs.

Are you writing `ResolveUrl("~/")`?

Also make sure that if you use `~/` that your controls are `runat="server"`.

Comment: saw that, I was editing as you were posting, I would have gave you +1

Comment: @hunter - 1) it works for *most* pages that use that master page, just not for some of them, which odd. There is no "ResolveUrl", they are just links. These are not controls, either. Here's the code:                     <ul>
                        <li class="first"><a href="~/sitemap.aspx">Sitemap</a></li>
                      
                        <li><a href="~/Privacy-Policy.aspx">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>

Comment: You can't do this: `<a href="~/sitemap.aspx">Sitemap</a>`. You have to write either `<a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/") %>sitemap.aspx">Sitemap</a>` or `<a href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/sitemap.aspx") %>">Sitemap</a>`

Comment: Hmm. I wonder why it is working on other pages? Or maybe it isn't, and no one has reported it to me? Just for the record (because this is such a silly issue), I didn't write this, this was just dumped on me, and I use ASP.NET like once a century... :) I will give this a shot and see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: Yeah, it happens, Hope I helped!

Comment: Hunter - Finally had a chance to try it out, that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue and the answer that worked best for me was to use the asp:Hyperlink control:

```
<asp:HyperLink ImageUrl="/Images/Logo.PNG" runat=server NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
```